# Mongoose match the regex of a child document in the match face of aggregation pipeline

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework, mongoose-populate

In mongoose I have the following two schemas,

**Role Schema**

```
const roleSchema = new Schema({
  roleName: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: [true, "Role Name is required"],
  },
  permissions: {
    type: [
      {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Permission",
      },
    ],
    required: [true, "Permissions are required"],
  },
});
```

**Permission Schema**

```
const permissionSchema = new Schema({
  permissionGroupName: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "Permission Group Name is required"],
    enum: {
      values: ["User Management", "Role Management"],
      // prettier-ignore
      message: "Permission Group Name should be either User Management or Role Management",
    },
  },
  permissionName: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "Permission Name is required"],
    unique: true,
  },
});

const Permission = mongoose.model("Permission", permissionSchema);

module.exports = Permission;
```

Here we are embedding the `permission` instances inside the `role` instance under the permissions property.

I am looking up those `permissions` from within the `roles` and use them in the `$match` stage as shown in the following pipeline.

**Then I have the following aggregation pipeline,**

```
[
  {
    '$lookup': {
      foreignField: '_id',
      from: 'permissions',
      localField: 'permissions',
      as: 'populatedPermissions'
    }
  },
  {
    '$match': {
      '$or': [
        { roleName: { '$regex': '.*de.*' } },
        { populatedPermissions: { '$regex': '.*de.*' } },
        {
          'populatedPermissions.permissionName': { '$regex': '.*de.*' }   // <--------- This regex is ignored
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  { '$sort': { roleName: 1 } },
  { '$skip': 0 },
  { '$limit': 10 }
]
```

**However, as I have pointed with an arrow in the above pipeline, my regex for the looked up `permission` is ignored.** (The returning results do not cater for that regex)

Does anyone know why and how to use that `permission` inside the `$or` array of my `$match` stage?

Comment: Can you add some sample input and output documents

Comment: The field `populatedPermissions` is an array of objects returned from the `$lookup` operation.